# How to draw tikz initial arrows like a greater-than sign

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am currently drawing some state diagrams of automata in Latex using the `tikz` library and I'm currently struggling to customize my starting arrows. The default starting arrow, while clear, isn't what I want. I want to be able to use basically a large greater than sign (>) to indicate the initial node instead of an arrow. I know there's some way to do it because my text book (Languages and Machines, Sudkamp 3rd edition) has these beautiful latex drawings with this exact feature:

[image]

which is comparable to my drawing but without the same starting arrow:

[image]

I can recognize that he probably changed the arrowheads for the loops with some variant of `>=latex`, but I am at a loss as to how one would customize the `initial` arrow like he did. Is there some easy way customize the starting arrow like this with `tikz`, especially with `tikzset` so that it wouldn't have to be redone in every drawing? My code (to produce second image) is currently

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows,calc}

% (failed attempts to replicate Sudkamp's arrow commented out below)
%\tikzset{initial text={}}
%\tikzset{initial distance=0.01cm}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=3cm,auto,]
      \node[state,initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
      \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
      \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
      \path[->] (q0) edge [loop above] node {a} ()
                (q0) edge node {b} (q1)
                (q1) edge node {a} (q2)
                (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
                (q2) edge [loop right] node {a} ()
                (q2) edge node {b} (q0);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you want (I'm not sure to have understood well your question).

I've searched a bit in the `tikz` manual, and the arrow tip closest to the first one of your first picture seems the `Classical TikZ Rightarrow`.

If you want the other arrows like the ones in your first picture, use `-Stealth`.

`arrows` is deprecated, use `arrows.meta`, instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=3cm,auto,]
        \node[state] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \path[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with \arrow{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[length=2mm]}}, decorate] (q0.west);
        \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
        \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
        \path[->] (q0) edge [loop above] node {a} ()
        (q0) edge node {b} (q1)
        (q1) edge node {a} (q2)
        (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
        (q2) edge [loop right] node {a} ()
        (q2) edge node {b} (q0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, draw two simple lines, I've also used the `Stealth` tip here, to show you the difference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=3cm,auto]
        \node[state] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \draw (q0.west) -- ++(-2mm,2mm);
        \draw (q0.west) -- ++(-2mm,-2mm);
        \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
        \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
        \path[-Stealth] (q0) edge [loop above, >=Stealth] node {a} ()
        (q0) edge node {b} (q1)
        (q1) edge node {a} (q2)
        (q1) edge [loop above, >=Stealth] node {b} (q1)
        (q2) edge [loop right, >=Stealth] node {a} ()
        (q2) edge node {b} (q0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = Zarko reminded me that `mathtools` already loads `amsmath`, I've removed the latter from my MWEs.

Comment: Perfect solution, looking at textbook I'm 99% certain this what the author did, adjusted all of them to 3mm and it looks exactly like it. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamCamilli You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

how about simple use of symbol $>$?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
            shorten > = 1pt, 
        node distance = 3cm and 3cm]
        \node[state] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-1pt,left=0pt of q0.west]{$>$};
        \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
        \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
        \path[->] (q0) edge [loop above] node {a} ()
        (q0) edge ["b"] (q1)
        (q1) edge ["a"] (q2)
        (q1) edge [loop above, "b"] (q1)
        (q2) edge [loop right, "a"] ()
        (q2) edge ["b"] (q0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

off-topic: `\mathtools` supersedes `amsmath`, so it is sufficient to load only `mathtools`.